# WinAppDriver - Unable to display combobox menu

Tags: c#, winappdriver

I'm using WinAppDriver with c#.
By finding a combobox element and click it, its menu (Combobox items) are displayed and disappears after that. How can I keep the combobox menu displayed?

By the way, I noticed that the "element.click()" method doesn't perform similar to the manual click using the mouse by the user. I noticed that since by clicking on that combobox, the menu get displayed and not disappeared.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
Actions action = new Actions(session);
var item = session.FindElementByName("Your element");
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
action.MoveToElement(item).Perform();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
action.Click();
action.Perform();
```

This will work for Combo Box